# correct Orientation of video in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, merge

i want to export video in correct orientation after recording from camera and merging. But video is in landscape mode.Don't know why this is in landscape. How to fix this issue. This is method of https://github.com/mkoehnke/MKOVideoMerge

```
+ (void)mergeVideoFiles:(NSArray *)fileURLs
         completion:(void(^)(NSURL *mergedVideoFile, NSError *error))completion {
NSLog(@"%@fileURLs", fileURLs);
NSLog(@"Start merging video files ...");

AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
NSMutableArray *instructions = [NSMutableArray new];

__block BOOL errorOccurred = NO;
__block CMTime currentTime = kCMTimeZero;
__block CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
__block int32_t highestFrameRate = 0;

[fileURLs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSURL *fileURL, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    #pragma unused(idx)

    NSDictionary *options = @{AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey:@YES};
    AVURLAsset *sourceAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:options];
    AVAssetTrack *videoAsset = [[sourceAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject];
    AVAssetTrack *audioAsset = [[sourceAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject];
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero)) { size = videoAsset.naturalSize; }

    int32_t currentFrameRate = (int)roundf(videoAsset.nominalFrameRate);
    highestFrameRate = (currentFrameRate > highestFrameRate) ? currentFrameRate : highestFrameRate;
    NSLog(@"* %@ (%dfps)", [fileURL lastPathComponent], currentFrameRate);

    // According to Apple placing multiple video segments on the same composition track can potentially lead to dropping frames
    // at the transitions between video segments. Therefore we trim the first and last frame of each video.
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html
    CMTime trimmingTime = CMTimeMake(lround(videoAsset.naturalTimeScale / videoAsset.nominalFrameRate), videoAsset.naturalTimeScale);
    CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(trimmingTime, CMTimeSubtract(videoAsset.timeRange.duration, trimmingTime));

    NSError *videoError;
    BOOL videoResult = [videoTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange ofTrack:videoAsset atTime:currentTime error:&videoError];

    NSError *audioError;
    BOOL audioResult = [audioTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange ofTrack:audioAsset atTime:currentTime error:&audioError];

    if(!videoResult || !audioResult || videoError || audioError) {
        if (completion) completion(nil, videoError? : audioError);
        errorOccurred = YES;
        *stop = YES;
    } else {
        AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *videoCompositionInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
        videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(currentTime, timeRange.duration);

        videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = @[[AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack]];
        [instructions addObject:videoCompositionInstruction];
        currentTime = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, timeRange.duration);

    }
}];

if (errorOccurred == NO) {
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    NSString *fileName = [MKOVideoMerge generateFileName];
    NSString *filePath = [MKOVideoMerge documentsPathWithFilePath:fileName];
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    AVMutableVideoComposition *mutableVideoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
     mutableVideoComposition.instructions = instructions;
     mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, highestFrameRate);
     mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = size;

    exportSession.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition;

    NSLog(@"Composition Duration: %ld seconds", lround(CMTimeGetSeconds(composition.duration)));
    NSLog(@"Composition Framerate: %d fps", highestFrameRate);

    void(^exportCompletion)(void) = ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completion) completion(exportSession.outputURL, exportSession.error);
        });
    };

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch (exportSession.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
                exportCompletion();
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:{
                exportCompletion();
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
                NSLog(@"Successfully merged video files into: %@", fileName);
                exportCompletion();
                break;
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown: {
                NSLog(@"Export Status: Unknown");
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting : {
                NSLog(@"Export Status: Exporting");
            }
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting: {
                NSLog(@"Export Status: Wating");
            }
        };
    }];
  }
}
```